# Can UI components built by codenameone export as library to all other languages such as C#, Objective-C and Java?

Tags: codenameone

I am surveying a cross-platform tool, and seems codenameone is a good choice for build an APP with WORA feature.

And I know codenameone have high extension capability to create extensions by add cn1lib format interfaces to translate many other language libraries to be interact with codenameone. (Is this statement true?)

But if I am developing a SDK which have UI components, how do I export this library to other mainstream languages such as C#, Objective-C, Swift, Java on Android, C++, C, JavaScript, ...... I know I of course have to create interfaces to bridge different language. How do I export SDK built by codenameone to work like that?

Thanks your kindly help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Codename One is designed to build complete apps. Libraries/SDK's for native projects are a different beast and they require native code.

I don't like saying "never" but this is probably not something that we would be able to address. Codename One has features such as GC (Garbage Collection) which wouldn't play nicely with a native app if it was packaged as an SDK.

The only cross platform tool that's designed for building SDK's (that I am aware of) is J2ObjC which is designed for sharing common Java library code between iOS & Android. I haven't used it much so I can't really say much about it.